# Query with OData without exposing ORM models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

In my web api 2 project, if I want to use OData library (which looks awesome and very tempting) for queries  over some properties, that would force the client side to know the exact properties of my database models. Is this a good practice? Is there a way to avoid this decouple?

For the following models:

```
public class LetterEntity
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}

        public string Title {get; set;}

        public string Content {get; set;}

        public string Source {get; set;}

        public DateTime SendingTime {get; set;} 

        public string AnotherWierdString {get; set;
        ...
    }

    public class LetterDTO
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}

        public string Title {get; set;}

        public string LetterContent {get; set;}

        public string Source {get; set;}

        public DateTime SendingTime {get; set;} 
    }

    public class LetterInsideFolderDTO 
    {
        public string Title {get; set;}

        public string Source {get; set;}
    }


public class LettersController : ApiController
{
    // In this approach method, I hate the fact that a LetterEntity must be used for the query.
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/letters")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<LetterInsideFolderDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<LetterEntity> query) 
    { 
        IQueryable<Letter> letters = db.Letters;

        var afterQuery = query.ApplyTo(letters)

        IQueryable<LetterInsideFolderDTO> dtos = afterQuery.ProjectTo<LetterInsideFolderDTO>(afterQuery)

        return dtos;
    }


    // Is there a way to do something like the following?:  
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/letters")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<LetterInsideFolderDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<LetterDTO> query) 
    { 
        IQueryable<Letter> letters = db.Letters;

        // Convert the query to work on the entities somehow? Should I use a mapping between LetterDTO to LetterEntity?
        // I only have a map from LetterEntity to LetterDTO
        var afterQuery = query.ApplyTo(letters)

        IQueryable<LetterInsideFolderDTO> dtos = afterQuery.ProjectTo<LetterInsideFolderDTO>(afterQuery)

        return dtos;
    }
}
```

Because of the fact that at the moment I take Entity model directly in the clients query, there is a strong coupling between clients and server.
For example if i want to query and get all the letters that has "abc" inside the `Content` field, I need to route to the following:

```
api/letters/?$filter=contains(Content,'abc')
```

If tomorrow I decide to change that property from "Content" to "LetterContent" all clients code will be broken.

How can I surpass it?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Please give me a concrete example,
I don't understand yet what HATEOAS are (if that helps me solve this issue),
How can documentation service help me? It'll still force clients to change their code if I decide to change my EDM models?

Comment: Another way around is don't use ODATA :), because ODATA, client must know EdmModel (ODATA schema) first in order to do query :)

Comment: Just expose your DTO which would be in essence a ResourceModel. See https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS

Comment: @CuongLe is there another alternative for many different queries? I don't want a different action for each query in my server

Comment: @SteveGreene could you please go into more details? How would that help me?

Comment: If your concern is letting users of your service know about your entity model, don't use that - create resource models which are the equivalent of view models in MVC that only expose what you want. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252294/why-is-there-no-wsdl-type-support-for-web-api

Comment: I don't understand how to query without letting clients know of the models, didn't find a sultion in your links

Comment: using a custom model just to output the result would not expose your models

Comment: @ARUN what do you mean by that? could you show an example maybe?

Comment: @S.Peter its nothing really, when the data is ready to send out, copy it to a new model having similar properties,but just different attribute names, in case you dont really want to tell the consumer about your internal structure..i dont know if this is what you want

Comment: What I don't like is that the type I have to take in my action ODataQueryOptions with Letter as the generic type - which is the entity model

Comment: I have provided very simple dynamic ODATA in here https://github.com/cuongle/DynamicOdata, you just provide the connection string, just the simple concept but it works

Answer (score 0):

> > if I want to use OData library (which looks awesome and very tempting) for queries over some properties, that would force the client side to know the exact properties of my database models. Is this a good practice?

It depends on what do you mean by "would force the client side to know the exact properties". There are two ways:

1. Use auto-generated proxies made by datasvcutil. Indeed, that would force the client side to know the exact properties since they are hard-coded in client-side. When server side is changed client would be broken - client/server are tightly coupled. In general it's bad, but usually if you need smth to get done quickly - datasvcutil is your tool.
2. Learn your client to read service document, so that he could dynamically decide what resources he may query. You have everything for it - service document, metadata.

Remember that OData is built on REST architecture which has a set of advantages that are achieved via set of constraints. Several of constraints are Addressability and HATEOAS.

**Addressability** means that each resource must have its address.

**HATEOAS** means that in any given moment, client, based on hypermedia in representation of current resource, must have all the information he needs to decide where to transit next.

In order to know where to transit client must

1. Know how to find resources(URL's) in the stream of data where he may transit. Like you get data with text and URL's - client must know how to find URL's. URL may have different meanings - like several URL's for CRUD operations.
2. Get that data with resources. In general client must know how to start querying service

First point is resolved via profiles. Profile - allows clients to learn about additional semantic associated with the resource representation (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6906). Consider it OData documentation. In case of OData your client must know that data in OData is represented via Atom or Json formats. Client must know principles of constructing queries to OData service, of getting specific record and so forth.

If client calls OData root address - smth like ...OData.svc, he would get list of all resources that he can query(service document). That is how second point is resolved.

You may come further and get metadata via $metadata suffix. That would give you all properties of resources.

Comment: I hope I made it clear now in my question. I want to be able to query by a field that is present ONLY in my entity model. It is not present in the DTO, therefore clients must know about it, which causes an ugly coupling. Can you maybe give a concrete example to my problem? I don't understand yet how using those HATEOAS will help me

Comment: @S.Peter I'm confused - you are asking whether its good practice that client side would know the exact properties of your database models and that would create coupling and later you are saying that you want to be able to query by a field that is present ONLY in your entity model. Why don't you expose your entity model then?

Comment: I say it's not good practice that client side would know the exact properties of database models and ask for a way to achieve the same query I described in my question (a query that relates to a property that is present only in database model) without exposing the database model

Comment: @S.Peter Ah I see. I don't know the way that client would make some requests to resources that he doesn't know - resources(OData entities) must have URL's and they must be discoverable by client. That's where service document comes to play. Аnother thing how client use service document. Since service document contains hypermedia you can teach client to understand it so that when server model is changed client wouldn't be broken - in that case there is no coupling.

Comment: but it is just a documentation..isn't it? If I decide my entities, clients must change their code as well, I want to avoid this scenario.

Comment: @S.Peter I would consider OData rules for creation of filters as documentation - it's like smth that must be hardcoded. Entities may change. - true. The fastest way, I think, would be to wrap most changed entities into views (consider it DTO), leave least changed as-is. The best way is to learn clients to read service documents and metadata - in that case you may change entities. Btw changing service is a whole different story - there are some strategies of changing, like make several versions for a while, then move from old to new one through 3xx redirection HTTP status codes

Comment: Like, this is documentation - http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398072. Service document -http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW (see it has urls - clients may be tought to use them). http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata - metadata (the same thing - clients may be tought to use it). You change entities, metadata is changed with service document. Since clients are smart - they are not broken.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that exposing your entities directly is a bad practice in most cases. I'd recommend DTOs in almost every case. It allows you to evolve your database and business logic without breaking the API. There are some great use cases for OData for example open data initiatives where the government publishes data as it is.

I had to built an app that was essentially grids over data with all the filtering and sorting options. I wanted to use OData but I did not find a way to do queries over entities but project to DTOs so I built my own library to convert jqgrid filters to IQueryable queries - https://github.com/KodarLtd/WebApiJQGridFilters Note that I do not recommend using this code as it is not full featured library and is not documented at all. I just provide it as evidence how firmly I believe in the DTO approach.

I would like to be proven wrong so I can use OData but return DTOs for my next project.

Comment: We are using ApiController and want to only use OData syntax for the GET operation. Is there a way to take ODataQueryOptions<LetterDTO> and have that query execute against the real EDM model (i.e Letter)? Or do I have to take parameter of type ODataQueryOptions<Letter> in my GET action?

Comment: As my answer states I believe this is not possible so I wrote my own thing to do pretty much that (although it is inferior to OData in every other way). If you find that I am wrong and you can achieve this with OData please let me know.

When I say it is not possible I mean that there is no way to set a property and be done with it. You can process the query options yourself and apply them to the corresponding entity. Here is an article that might help if you go down that route - http://www.ben-morris.com/parsing-odata-queries-decoupled-data-entities-webapi/